# Duration in days over DST boundary or across timezones

Tags: datetime, timezone, dst, duration, iso8601

I'm wondering if ISO-8601 or any other popular standards about time address the issue of duration in days when the interval spans across a DST boundary?

For example, duration in days between `2017-03-01T12:00:00-05:00` and `2017-03-02T12:00:00-05:00` is clearly `1 day`.

But what about duration in days between `2017-03-11T12:00:00-05:00` (DST off) and `2017-03-12T12:00:00-04:00` (DST on)?  On one hand, it's noon until noon the next day -- which seems like `1 day`.  On the other hand, it is only `23 hours` of actual elapsed time.

Furthermore, whatever the semantics are, would they also apply across different geographic timezones (say noon one day in NYC vs. noon the next day in London)?

Comment: Seems Contextual in what is wanted.  I think you make the case that there cannot be a standard.  This also sneaks up in many built in functions in reporting and SQL libraries.    11:59 pm to 12:01 am will be 1 full day in many built in function libraries.   Specific to your use case you could argue the time is the time, DST is not relevant,  an hour  disappears and an hour is duplicated once per year.  This is why I use UTC extensively.

Comment: [This C++ library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) allows you to choose the context in which arithmetic takes place:  in UTC, or in a specific local time with respect to a specific time zone.  Both computations are useful, and the programmer has to decide which is correct for any given situation.  The library is under consideration for standardization into the C++ standard, and if accepted, the C++ standard will then have something to say about this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant parts of ISO 8601:2004(E)

> **2.2.6**
> **calendar day**
> time interval starting at midnight and ending at the next midnight, the latter being also the starting instant of the next calendar day
>
> NOTE 1 A calendar day is often also referred to as day
>
> NOTE 2 The duration of a calendar day is 24 hours; except if modified by:
>
> - the insertion or deletion of leap seconds, by decision of the International Earth Rotation Service (IERS), or
> - the insertion or deletion of other time intervals, as may be prescribed by local authorities to alter the time scale of local time.
>
> **2.2.7**
> **day**
> 〈duration〉 duration of a calendar day
>
> NOTE The term "day" applies also to the duration of any time interval which starts at a certain time of day at a certain calendar day and ends at the same time of day at the next calendar day
>
> ...
>
> **4.2.2.1**
>
> ... no provisions have been made to prevent ambiguities in expressions that result from discontinuities in the time scale of local time (e.g. daylight saving time)

In summary, one should be very careful with the term "day".  Though the common "standard day" is 24 hours in duration, both leap seconds and local time zone transitions can affect its duration.

As a rule of thumb, I tend to think about a *day* in terms of calendar units by default.  That is, like *month* and *year*, it is part of a calendar system, not a timekeeping system.  Think of the those three parts working in unison to produce a square below:

[image: calendar]

Conversely, units of *time* are all based on the SI [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second), which is *exactly*:

> the duration of 9,192,631,770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom

Our other *time* units are all derived from there.  60 seconds make a minute.  60 mintues make an hour.

Though we would prefer to define days in terms of an exact amount of time, we cannot always reconcile the two because of time zones, daylight saving time, and leap seconds.